# ExtJS 6 - How to show tips on charts?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

We have been using `tips` configuration of `series` in order to set interactive tips for **ExtJS 4 & 5**. But with **ExtJS 6**, it does not work anymore. So what is the proper way of showing tips using **ExtJS 6** chart package?

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    field: 'count',
    showInLegend: true,
    donut: false,
    tips: {
        trackMouse: true,
        width: 140,
        height: 40,
        renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
            this.update(storeItem.get('name') + ':' + storeItem.get('count'));
        }
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the tooltip `renderer` method arguments have been swapped around between versions, otherwise your [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1238) is almost there.  The `this` keyword appears to be the series rather than the tooltip - it's best not to rely on the JS context in ExtJS anyway and Sencha appear to be making efforts while refactoring the API, to ensure that you can consistently expect a reference to the relevant component as the first argument of any callback.

If you look at the [series-tooltip](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Series-cfg-tooltip) in the API it will confirm that the first argument is a reference to the tooltip and the second argument is the selected record - so you can update a tooltip as follows:

```js
{
    xtype: 'pie'
    // ...
    tooltip: {
        // ...
        renderer: function(tip, item){
            tip.update(item.get('name') + ': ' + item.get('count'));
        }
    }
}
```

[**» updated fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1257)

Answer (score 1):

Seems you switched from `ext-charts` to `sencha-charts`.

It is no more `tips` property for `Series` :

ExtJS 4 - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Series-cfg-tips

ExtJS 6 - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Series

Try **tooltip** property it should be the same as **tips** before

Comment: now I see an **empty** and **long** text as I uploaded it here: http://pasteboard.co/2CAv9iEb.png

Answer (score 1):

```
tooltip: {
  trackMouse: true,
  renderer: function(toolT, storeItem) {
              toolT.setHtml('dummy tooltip');
  }
}
```

Try this.